# how to overcome ui-routing with default state

Tags: forms, angular-ui-router, submission

Here is my HTML Code

```
<PRE>
    form action="#"  method="post"
    input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" 
    input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" 
    input type="hidden" name="w3ls_item" value="Asus Laptop" 
    input type="hidden" name="amount" value="880.00"
    button type="submit" class="w3ls-cart"> Add to cart /button
   /form
</PRE>
```

Here is my Javascript for FORM

```
<pre>
    w3ls.render();
    w3ls.cart.on('w3sb_checkout', function (evt) {
    var items, len, i;
    if (this.subtotal() > 0) {
    items = this.items();
    for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    }
    }
    });

</pre>
```

and my APP.JS code for UI-ROUTER

```
<pre>
    routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/pages/home');
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
    url: '/pages/home',
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'
    })
</pre>
```

When i click on "Add to cart" button its taking me to default page how can i make it to point to the javascript function?

Thanks in advance!